# how to get url after Equal sign in php

Tags: url, get

I have a url that looks something like this:

```
http://sitename.com?url=domin.com
```

and I need to take the part of the url after the Equal sign
How do I display the value after the equal sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in php, you do:

```
<?=$_GET['url']?>
```

In java you do :

```
var split = location.search.replace('?', '').split('=')
```

`split[0]` is your var name, and split[1] is your var value. You actually don't really need jQuery for that piece of code ;)

Splitting multiple variables can be done like that:

```
var split = location.search.replace('?', '').split('&').map(function(val){
  return val.split('=');
});
```

You can access variable name by `split[index][0]` and value by `split[index][1]`.

Of course you can use the second snippet instead of the first one for one variable too.

Or, for jQuery, you could use this plugin : https://github.com/mattsnider/jquery-plugin-query-parser

Comment: Very good Thank you I want using your javascript code But the problem came What is wrong in this code?

<script>
var split = location.search.replace('?', '').split('=')
window.location = "http://"split[1]""
</script>

Comment: You are using it wrong:D Try this: `var split = location.search.replace('?', '').split('=') window.location;` then, on the second line you do: `alert(split);` OR you do `console.log(split);`, in which case, in google chrome you right click somewhere on the page, select "inspect element", then you click console and refresh..you should have the values there!

Comment: Yes
Thank you so much
  I wanted something that was